# Is disabling the Windows 7 Desktop window manager a bad idea?

Tags: windows-7, memory, process, cpu-usage

I'm thinking about disabling the dwm.exe process. It seems that I can do fine without the fancy feature of [Wind]+[Tab], and am generally needing to cut memory.

Does it have unintended side-effect?

Comment: to see what uses most memory run RAMMap: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2010/08/13/introduction-to-the-new-sysinternals-tool-rammap.aspx

Comment: Why not just add more memory.  My dwm.exe uses about 726k according to task manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no functionality related side effects except some minor UI changes, such as:

1. You won't get Thumbnail previews in the taskbar.
2. Aero peek will be disabled(You have to click instead of just hovering)
3. You won't be able to change Taskbar colour.

One advantage of disabling DWM is it reduces the boot up time.